# How to npm install on Heroku

Tags: json, node.js, heroku, laravel-5

I would like to to deploy my app on Heroku through bitbucket-pipeline.
Flow is as follows.

1. composer install
2. npm install
3. Laravel-Mix(gulp task and brouserify and so on...)

These will be needed because "vendor" and "node_modules" are written in gitignore.
Now 2 and 3 are failed to build.
I guess it caused package.json or bitbucket-pipelines.yml, but I do not know how to code. Please give me solutions?

※nodejs buildpack is already installed
※I can npm install in Heroku app when I tried "heroku run bash", then "npm install"

Here is my "package.json" and "bitbucket-pipelines.yml" (Laravel5.4)

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  }
}
```

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
// bitbucket-pipelines.yml

image: phpunit/phpunit:5.0.3
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - composer install
          - npm install
          - npm run production
          - git push https://heroku: test-stg.git HEAD
```

Comment: have you checked logs?

Comment: yes, but there were many errors...

Comment: sh: 1: cross-env: not found 
Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.

Comment: remote:        npm ERR! node v7.6.0        
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2        
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE        
remote:        npm ERR! undefined postinstall: `npm run production`

remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the undefined postinstall script 'npm run production'.        
remote:        npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.        
remote:        npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,        
remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.

Comment: remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:        
remote:        npm ERR!     npm run production        
remote:        npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:        
remote:        npm ERR!     npm bugs        
remote:        npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:        
remote:        npm ERR!     npm owner ls        
remote:        npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: I am so sorry my terrible comments....I do not know how to edit my question...

Comment: `edit` small grey button below your question, `npm install` were successful?

Comment: Thanks, Ivan. I removed node_modules folder and install again, then solved. I used a fresh package.json before installing modules.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/laravel-54-dev-npm-run-dev-error

Please see for your reference, I use package.json file that Taylor said.

Comment: in heroku you need a procfile, which specifies the command heroku would run for you to download libs and start server

Comment: Thanks for your information, Rishabh Jain. I did not know that, I will check !!